# How can I use Control D in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl

I am a beginner in perl. How can I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to indicate that I am done with sending the inputs? I am using Active Perl in Windows and not in Unix.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Windows cmd.exe, try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>  to signal the end of file (EOF).

Source: http://code.activestate.com/lists/activeperl/7343/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use F6  function key to denote end of your inout in windows